# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist for a model with foreginkey with standard user model

Tags: python, django

I have this issue :RelatedObjectDoesNotExist

I add a UserProfile to my models (for now there is only avatar to be added to User Model.

It is not mandatory to add a picture. So some userProfile are null. The proble is when I edit Userform and ProfileUserform. I had an error :
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /accounts/user_edit/
User has no profile.

I try to add a try: except in views but seems not working

Models.Py:

```
   class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')  # il s'agit d'ajouter des infos au modele User

    #  add any additional attributes needed
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', blank=True) # avatar of the user in director profile_pics

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email
```

Views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url='account/sign_up.html')
def user_edit(request):
    # Get info from "both" forms
    # It appears as one form to the user on the .html page
    user_form = UserFormEdit(instance=request.user)

    profile_form = UserProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)


    # Check to see both forms are valid
    if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
        # Prepare Save User Form to Database
        user = user_form.save()
        profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)

        # Check if they provided a profile picture
        if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
            print('found it')
            # If yes, then grab it from the POST form reply
            profile.profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic']
        profile.save()
        messages.success(request, 'User updated')

    return render(request, 'account/user_edit.html',
                  {'user_form': user_form,
                   'profile_form': profile_form}
                   )
```

Error is on profile_form = UserProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)

because request is null....

I would like to have possibility to add or edit UserProfile info after creation of User. So it should render a empty UserProfileForm if it does not already exists or instance user.profile data if exists

thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out the profile exists, and if not use a new instance.

```
try:
  profile = request.user.profile
except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
  profile = UserProfile(user=request.user)
profile_form = UserProfileForm(instance=profile)
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you have a `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist` error originates from the fact that a user does not *per se* has a related `Profile`. So `request.user.profile` can fail.

You can fetch the `Profile` if it exists with `.filter(..).first()`:

```
@login_required(login_url='account/sign_up.html')
def user_edit(request):
    user = request.user
    profile = Profile.objects.filter(user=user).first()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserFormEdit(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.instance.user = user
            profile = profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'User updated')
            return redirect('some_view')
    else:
        user_form = UserFormEdit(instance=user)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(instance=profile)
    return render(
        request,
        'account/user_edit.html',
        {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form}
    )
```

Furthermore a form can handle files as well, and I advice you to let the form handle the work, since it will usually be less error-prone, perform proper validations, and remove a lot of boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

While it is completely fine to have two related models with an object existing only in one, in this case, it might be better to always have a profile even if it is empty. I would suggest creating a user profile on user create.

Anyways if you want to continue with the existing code, a simple way to handle creating a UserProfile on edit would be to do something like the below, in your view

```
try:
    profile = request.user.profile
except RelatedObjectDoesNotExist:  # I feel it should actually throw AttributeError here
    profile = UserProfile(user=request.user)  # this is a dummy profile and won't be save until the form is saved
    profile_form = UserProfileForm(instance=profile)
```

If you do want to create a profile on creation of users, you can add it to the save of the form or model.

```
# in form
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    is_create = self.instance.pk is None
    return_value = super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    if is_create:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=self.instance)
    return return_value

# or in user model
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    is_create = self.pk is None
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    if is_create:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=self)
    return self

# or in the view
def create(request):
    ...
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=self)
    ...
```